# Macbook Pro Retina 2015 (12,1) Ubuntu 15.04 install from live CD to SD Card

Tags: boot, 15.04, macbook-pro, sd-card

I want to do a full install Linux on my MBP 2015 13-inch. I'm using an SD Card because I do not want to touch the SSD.

I've used this tutorial:http://www.michaelevans.org/blog/2013/01/15/boot-ubuntu-from-an-sd-card-on-your-macbook-air/

The issue is with OS X 10.10, apparently Apple has changed the way 10.10 boots and it prevents rEFIt from working the way it's supposed to in the tutorial. I can finish the installation and the when I reboot, the Ubuntu partition doesn't show up.

How can I do this without rEFIt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, rEFInd is the successor of refit, since this stopped their development  long time ago.

Now as the rEFInd web page indicates, the new 0.8.4 version works as it should work but, if the automatic installer fails you can always follow the manual installation, indicated in the [same web page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/yosemite.html).

Now I'm not aware if refind can search in the SD cards, I believe that is a hardware thing, but don't listen to me in this, I'm not fully aware of this.

Check the web page, is really complete and really clever on the instructions.

As an extra comment, Yosemite is a really unstable system, if you want to use both (ubuntu and OS X) I personally recommend to downgrade to Maveriks, since this is more friendly with the boot.

Good luck with this. :D

Comment: I just want to do a full install on a USB flash drive or SD card without messing with OS X's boot partition or messing with the SSD. I'm surprised more people with Yosemite haven't tried to install Ubuntu/Mint on an attached drive. I'm not talking about a live install, but a full install, it worked fine on the 2012 MBA with Yosemite 10.10.3, I'm not sure what's different on the MBPr